# Passing AsyncTask result to different Activites

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is what i have so far:

- I have 3 activities
- In every activity is a connection to a Database to send and
  recieve data
- Every input (String) and Output (JSONObject) works the same
- At first i implemented an asynctask in every activity to send and recieve the data
- The result is handeld in the activity that started the task
- To reduce the code i transfered the asynctask to an extra class
- Every activity implements an interface "AsyncResponse"

My Problem is:
With the implementation i use delegate to set a reference to the calling activity. I cant find a way to change the delegation. If i want to create a new asynctask in my second activity and try to delegate it, it shows an incompatible types error.

**So is there a way that i can send the asyncresults back to a specific calling activity?**

**Example for the implementation**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  AsyncResponse

    public void startAsync(String[] stringArray)
    {
        AsyncTaskRequest objMyTask = new AsyncTaskRequest(this);
       // objMyTask.delegate = this; // *.delegate in another Task in not possible
        objMyTask.execute(stringArray);
    }
```

**AsyncResponse Interface**

```
    public interface AsyncResponse
    {
        void taskDone(JSONObject x);
    }
```

**Example for the AsyncTask**

```
    public class AsyncTaskRequest extends android.os.AsyncTask<String, 
    Void, JSONObject>
    {
    //MainActivity delegate = null;

    private AsyncResponse delegate;

    public AsyncTaskRequest(AsyncResponse delegation)
    {
        delegate=delegation;
    }


    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... postData)
    {.......}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject x)
    {
       delegate.taskDone(x);
    }

    }
```

Comment: As it was stated in bazillion similar question - use interface

Comment: I thought i do with my AsyncResponse interface.
The other questions i have seen only called back one activity

Comment: ugh i didnt see it at the first time because you are using activity class instead this interface(delegate) ... read some basics about object oriented programming ... your interface is like animal ... and activies are cat and dog ... your asynctask can store cat ... and asking why you cant store dog(reason is obvious - the dog is not a cat) ... and you totaly forgot about animal

Comment: My question is not why i cant store dog. My question is, how  could i create a solution that my AsyncTask could store both types (cat and dog) and reacts to the input.

All activites implements the AsyncResponse interface, so all of them could react if the AsyncTask fires the Method taskDone.

If the AsyncTask would store references to the activies it could fire the Method for the input Activity.

Like Model and View.

How would you solve this?

Comment: please chceck your code again ... you are trying store animal in cat ... which is posible only if animal to store is a cat

Comment: Tanks for your thoughts =)

It works. So to help people who may look for the answer:

instead of 

MainActivity delegate = null

build the delegation in the asynctask constructor:
private AsyncResponse delegate;

    public AsyncTaskRequest(AsyncResponse delegation)
    {
        delegate=delegation;
    }

Comment: some future read ... problem which you will face when you are storing Activity in asynctask: https://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/10/asynctask-screen-rotation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a listener inside you ASyncTask

In your ASyncTask:

```
public class AsyncTaskRequest extends android.os.AsyncTask<String, 
    Void, JSONObject>
    {

    private OnTaskCompleted listener;
    public interface OnTaskCompleted{
         void onTaskCompleted(Boolean output);
    }

    private AsyncResponse delegate;

    public AsyncTaskRequest(AsyncResponse delegation)
    {
        delegate=delegation;
    }


    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... postData)
    {.......}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject x)
    {
       delegate.taskDone(x);
       if (listener != null)
         listener.onTaskCompleted(result);
    }

    }
```

and in your java file call this function:

```
public OnTaskCompleted listener =new OnTaskCompleted() {
        public void onTaskCompleted(Boolean output) {
            //your code here
       }
};
```